# Add 6 items together to give a total, but by not adding their values together

Tags: mysql, math, count, sum

Bit of a newbie and probably a very basic question to you, but is driving me mad.

I have a mysql table. I have a record which has a record id, and six other fields which contain names of photographs.

So, 
Record_id, photo1, photo2, photo3, photo4, photo5, photo6

I want have have the end result where I have a column called 'TOTAL' which shows the number of how many records have photographs in them as a TOTAL. So, Record 1 may have a total of 5 photographs, record 2 may have 3 photographs, and record 3 may have a total of NO records for that record etc?

Now some of the photographs names which are uploaded to the field may contain numbers, ie, photo244.jpg, or pic3993.jpg etc - so I don't want these numbers added together, I am just looking for whether the field has a name in it etc, and this would be counted as 1 to add to the total. So the end result in on the page is that record 13 (for example) has a total of 4 photographs etc - sorry if not a good explanation!

It may have something to do with SUM or COUNT, but have spent ages trying to get combination or correct key/syntax! Can anyone help please by giving an example of the mysql select statement - would be grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that if there is no photo, then the field photoX is null or is empty.
So use [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) for output 0 if the field is null or empty, 1 else.

```
SELECT Record_id
     , 
          CASE WHEN (photo1 IS NULL OR photo1 = '') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        + CASE WHEN (photo2 IS NULL OR photo2 = '') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        + CASE WHEN (photo3 IS NULL OR photo3 = '') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        + CASE WHEN (photo4 IS NULL OR photo4 = '') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        + CASE WHEN (photo5 IS NULL OR photo5 = '') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        + CASE WHEN (photo6 IS NULL OR photo6 = '') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
      AS Total
FROM myTable
```

Comment: +1 A slightly simpler formulation might be of the form `CASE WHEN photo1 > '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + ...` .

Comment: WOW! You have no idea how fantastic you guys are! The above answer from Scorpi0 was perfect! Could I think you others (Mark, Ed, Michael etc) for having the time to reply also. You are all great guys - many thank you's!!!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will give you a count by `Photo1`, `Photo2`, etc.:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN photo1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS Photo1Count,
  SUM(CASE WHEN photo2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS Photo2Count,
  SUM(CASE WHEN photo3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS Photo3Count,
  SUM(CASE WHEN photo4 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS Photo4Count,
  SUM(CASE WHEN photo5 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS Photo5Count
FROM MyTable
```

Something like this will count how many rows have at least one photograph:

```
SELECT SUM (
  CASE WHEN
    photo1 IS NOT NULL OR
    photo2 IS NOT NULL OR
    photo3 IS NOT NULL OR
    photo4 IS NOT NULL OR
    photo5 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END)
FROM MyTable
```

*Note that these queries are for grand totals.* They don't show activity by row. If activity by row is needed, try the answers from Scorpi0 or Michael Sivolobov.

Comment: I understand the OP's question to mean that he wants results on a row-by-row basis, not as a grand total for all rows.

Comment: Mark - thanks for the heads-up. You're probably right; it's tough to tell. I'll update my answer so it's clear that it's a "grand total" and not a row-by-row count.

Answer (score 0):

It will the best query:

```
SELECT
    Record_id,
    (6 - IFNULL(photo1,1) - IFNULL(photo2,1) - IFNULL(photo3,1) - IFNULL(photo4,1) - IFNULL(photo5,1) - IFNULL(photo6,1)) AS TOTAL
FROM
    table
```

Comment: Assumes that an "empty" photo will be NULL.